# Can Ubuntu be installed on an Apple laptop?

Tags: macbook, apple

Quite simply, can one replace the default operating system on an Apple laptop (i.e. Apple Mac OS) with Ubuntu, just like you could on a PC?

Or are they locked-down, so that this is not possible?

I haven't used an Apple computer in over twenty years (since the um, Apple II I think it was!)... But I've seen their stuff in stores and they make some neat lappys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so. I have mentioned the steps required to achieve this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os/550027#550027).