# Remove Mac OS X entirely and install Ubuntu

Tags: macbook, 14.10

I already formatted my hard drive in my Macbook Air and installed Ubuntu. However, after installing it doesn't seem to boot. What am I missing? I created two partitions, 250GB each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of installing Ubuntu on a Mac.

1. Legacy Boot - Use the Mac variant of Ubuntu which you can download from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso).

Install rEFInd before you install Ubuntu. Now, create a partition for Ubuntu using either Disk Utility or GParted and install normally. When you reboot after the installation finishes, rEFInd will load and give you an option to select either OS X or Ubuntu.

This is the easier method and is convenient if you are dual booting.

2. EFI Boot - Use the normal variant of Ubuntu.

This method is slightly tough because you will have to delete the grub partition created by the Ubuntu installer (on a FAT partition) and install grub on an HFS partition, failing which your mac will not boot. However, this method works better if you want to completely replace OS X with Ubuntu.

Refer to [my earlier post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os/550027#550027) for steps to the EFI Boot method.

Comment: Woot I installed the Ubuntu Mac version and it automatically did everything for me. Just erase hard drive, install and boot into Ubuntu. I tried your guide with Ubuntu 14.10 though, and failed at the step getting the PPA for mactel-boot because it does not have 14.10 package yet.