# Need to dual-boot Ubuntu with Yosemite

Tags: dual-boot, mac, 14.10, macosx

I initially followed [this](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/11/ubuntu-on-a-macbookpro-82-running-yosemite/) guide. I installed rEFInd. I booted from my USB, installed Ubuntu, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu, I get a black screen with a blinking `_` and nothing really happens. Pleas help.

It would also be fine if you could show me a way to wipe OSX and install Ubuntu. Athough, i know i wont be getting any firmware updates later on.

Answer (score 0):

The system is unbootable because the Mac bootloader expects the EFI partition to be formatted as HFS+, the typical Mac filesystem, while the Ubuntu installer actually formats it as VFAT.

Refer to my [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os/550027#550027) for detailed steps to install Ubuntu properly on a Mac.

Comment: This overwrites osx with ubuntu ?