# Different computer with the same hard drive won't boot

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu on a MacBook and everything was working fine.  A few weeks into using it I realized that the Mac had a few problems with the keyboard.

I had another MacBook of the exact same model so I swapped hard drives but now the new Mac won't boot Ubuntu or even recognize it.

Originally, after the Ubuntu install I had to boot into the live CD and manually change the boot order with this command:

```
efibootmgr -o 0,80
```

However, when I try to do this now it says:

```
boot entry 0 does not exist
```

I can see my disk there as `/dev/sda` with partitions `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda3`
.

Any suggestions on how to get it to boot? Just a note, I am not dual booting this is just Ubuntu by itself.

EDIT

My installation is Encrypted with LVM as well.  This may be causing more issues.

Comment: Not an expert here, but I think that with Macs you also have to resync the partitions again with rEFIt.

Answer (score 0):

After following this answer

[Trying to single install on MacBook Pro but won't automatically boot from new OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os)

I was able to get it to boot with a live USB's grub menu.  However, something went wrong with the rest of the steps and while trying a few other things I formatted my boot partition.

I had to reinstall and transfer my files from backup.  Everything is working now from a fresh Ubuntu install.