# GRUB failed to install. can't boot neither windows nor Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub-efi

I tried to install Ubuntu, but failed. I was trying to dual boot it with windows 7 x64 professional. Also my hardware is pretty old. My CPU is Intel core i3, 4 GB ram.
At First I got an efi partition error so I made an efi partition then I tried to proceed with the installation, but it crashed. I got an error saying that gurb failed to install & that this is a fatal error.
After that it somehow booted & opened Firefox & made me make an Ubuntu one account to report my problem. After that it asked to restart my PC so I did, but I'm now left with a black screen of "GNU GRUB version 2.04"
"minimal bash like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub>  "

What do I do now? Sorry for the badly formatted question, but I'm typing on mobile & I can't do anything useful on it.
Someone please help! I'm as noob as it gets. I want to boot to either os & I will find my way out from there.

Comment: Sounds like you have a legacy Win7 install, but did a UEFI Ubuntu install.  How the install media boots is how it installs (UEFI), and how the media boots is selected by BIOS/UEFI settings, so check those and ensure legacy is preferred over UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

So when you reboot you always get that limited grub terminal?
And guessing even thoigh windoze7 is old your PC is UEFI...
Full notes are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os/550027#550027) but below are the basics from rohiths answer (your disk probably isn't gpt btw);
At the grub console; `grub> ls`

> (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos) (hd1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt3) (hd2,gpt2) (hd2,gpt1)

You may not get exactly the same results as this, but you’ll have some similar options.
Now, find the partition which contains your user's home directory.
`ls (hd2,gpt2)/home`

> rohith/

Keep trying until you find it.
The result from the last step has two parts: (hdX,gptY). You need to keep the hdX part, but go through all the gptY options looking for a /boot/grub directory.
`ls (hd2,gpt2)/boot/grub`

> unicode.pf2 [...] grub.cfg

Now you want to set this as your root for further commands.
`set root=(hd2,gpt2)`
The only way to boot properly was to use the UUID of the drive. To get it
`ls -l (hd2,gpt2)`
Note down the UUID. You'll have to type it manually in the next step.
`linux /boot/vmlinuz〈...tab here!...〉.efi.signed root=UUID=〈the UUID from above〉<br/> The GRUB console can do tab completion, so if you just type out the vmlinuz part and hit tab, then hit . and tab again, you won't have to type the whole file name. make sure that the efi.signed part is present<br/> Now, set the initial RAM disk.<br/>` initrd /boot/initrd〈...tab here!...〉`<br/> You should be able to boot with the command<br/>` boot`
This will reboot and get you to the login screen as if you had a perfect install and rebooted. If you have an internet connection you can get the system up-to-date at this point but do NOT reboot untill you fix grub. NOTE the boot partition is probably incorrect, the boot loader may need to be reformatted as FAT32 with mount point /boot/efi with flags (boot,esp) which can be checked and if needed fixed simply using gparted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I, unfortunately, did not understand much of it, but it nonetheless helped me understand other concepts. I fixed my problem by booting Ubuntu form my USB drive and installing the Ubuntu boot repair software. That solved all my problems with Ubuntu, but I still can't boot windows. It shows as an option in the boot menu, but it gives two errors: "cant find command parttool" & "invalid EFI file path"
Anyway. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Again this pretty old but this helped me enter a custom grub entry for an old windoze version in the past https://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8-grub-error-cant-find-command check it our.