# grub command line is always shown after reinstalling grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I have two hard disks, one which contains Windows 10 and the other one contains Ubuntu (20.04). The ubuntu hard disk has full disk encryption using LVM.

The problem I'm seeing is that every time I try to boot into my Ubuntu disk I get thrown at the grub command line. I know how to make it boot but it's very annoying having to do that every single time I want to switch operating systems. I've already tried to `sudo update-grub2` or try to remove and reinstall grub. I still get the same exact error.

After browsing online I came across the `boot-repair` tool which should hopefully solve my problems but it ends up that it still won't work correctly as I expect it to. This is the output from `boot-repair` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wthpKpVRyV/

These are the contents of my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax pcie_ports=compat"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Don't use boot-repair. Can you edit your question and add the contents of your grub file please? Open a terminal and trype `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and copy & paste the text (don't change anything yet).

Comment: I have now edited my question @darth_epoxy with the contents of it

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend that you add these lines;**
Open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` or use gedit.
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
**Add this for the CMDLINE but this is speculative and after a few sucessful boots you can change it back. So just comment out with # rather than delete any lines. Also you can tweak this grub file if you find out more information down the line.**
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax pcie_ports=compat"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
**And uncomment this line;**
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
**Save using the same filename (in nano use Ctrl+O)**
After you save make sure to update grub or nothing happens!
Type `sudo update-grub` and this will generate a new cfg file.
Type `sudo shutdown -r now` and report back the result.
**Note: This will make you boot to the grub menu which will help diagnose problems if this Answer is incomplete. You can change that back at any time afterwards.**

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I have updated my original answer to show my current `/etc/default/grub`. When I run `sudo update-grub` it also says it sees my windows hard drive but when I get to the grub menu running the manual commands I don't see the entry either.

Comment: Bugger. If you are getting the grub console instead of the grub menu, what were you typing to make it boot? There is a long form answer here for grub console problems and it might be wortha  read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280087/grub-failed-to-install-cant-boot-neither-windows-nor-ubuntu/1280155#1280155

Comment: This is what I type to make it boot

`set root=(hd1,2)
set prefix=(hd1,2)/grub
insmod normal
normal`