# Lubuntu 20.04.4 mkfs.hfsplus command not found

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, lubuntu

I had installed Lubuntu 20.04 on an old MacBook Pro 3,1 in a dual-boot setup with OSX. I decided I liked lubuntu, and opted to wipe my drive & make it a Linux only machine. So last night, I downloaded a fresh iso image of Lubuntu 20.04.4 from lubuntu.me, and set it up on a USB stick.

During installation, I chose the erase disk option, and the install went well. I then began following the instructions in the solution for [Trying to single install on MacBook Pro but won't automatically boot from new OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os).

At this point, I can boot to my HDD as long as I use the grub menu on the live installer USB I made earlier. Without it, it results in a flashing folder icon, but the instructions told me to expect that, and the next steps would fix it.

Again, everything went well until getting to the step requiring the command mkfs.hfsplus (full command in the above link). Upon entering the command, I receive the error “mkfs.hfsplus: command not found”. I attempted to apt install hfsprogs and mactel-utils.  Hfsprogs was already latest version, mactel-utils returned a 404 error.

I have also not run any updates or installed any applications yet, as I wanted to eliminate as many variables as possible.

**Is there any way to fix or workaround this?**

I can supply a text copy of my terminal session if that would help.

Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Answer (score 0):

After all the frustration with trying to get lubuntu working, Xubuntu installed and booted perfectly on the first try with no special EFI or grub tricks. Plus, Xfce seems to be playing very nicely with the Mac. Anyone looking to put Linux on a Mac, just use Xubuntu.  It’s easy, and it works great.